# Esper - remove old events from runtime

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have a question concerning the CEP-Engine Esper:

How can I remove old events from a runtime to free memory?

Thank you.

Edit: Sorry, I meant the EPRuntime, not the JVM runtime

Answer (score 0):

Esper doesn't keep removed events in memory. However the JVM may do that until a garbage collection kicks in.

Comment: so, does esper automatically discard old events and the gc removes them, if new memory is needed?